# Node Data Retrieving Error 1

Tags: node.js

I linked the picture of my folder, and the error I'm getting.

I have two files app.js and index.js:

app.js takes data from index.js. The problem I'm having is that it is not.

Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye6o0.png

Comment: Please do not post code in linked images. Instead copy paste any relevant code (in a codeblock) and error messages into your question. If you do that, you are much more likely to attract a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
   var flight = require('./index.js')
```

Comment: But I only have an index.js and app.js files.

Comment: console.log(flight.getinfo());

Comment: hmm not sure. although one thing i'll recommend is to put `'use strict';` at the very top of every single source file. this will help with debugging and writing cleaner code, etc. more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode